# How can I modify this line of sight algorithm to accept rays which pass through corners?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working on a pathfinding algorithm based on Theta*, a variant of A* which provides a good system for pathfinding which is not constrained to a grid, even though the terrain/obstructions are based on a grid pattern. This system requires a line of sight algorithm to determine whether or not a particular path is obstructed.

I found [this](http://playtechs.blogspot.com/2007/03/raytracing-on-grid.html) extremely useful line of sight algorithm, and I've successfully implemented it in my code. Unfortunately, it considers the following to be an invalid path:

[image: grid]

However, for my purposes, I want such a path to be considered valid. I've tried to modify the algorithm by detecting whether or not a point is on the line itself using the basic `y = mx + b` formula, but the algorithm's inconsistencies prevent me from relying on such a system.

Is there any efficient way to modify this algorithm to allow such a path? Is there another algorithm that would work better? Keep in mind that the start and end points of the path will *not* necessarily be confined to a grid, so all points use `double` precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the code you reference actually omits to explicitly handle the case where the line goes through a grid point (where four squares touch). You need to check for `error == 0`.

In this case, at most one of the four squares touching the grid point may be blocked to still have a valid path.

Regards,
Erich

Comment: Alright, cool, that works. But could you just point me why exactly it does? I *sort of* understand it, but I don't completely.

Comment: Right, I get that, but could you elaborate on what the `error` value does in general?

Comment: From what I see by just skimming the sources you referenced (the last section using integer math), when passing through a grid point, the LOS is actually divided into two (or more) similar segments. As the author notes, his algorithms will always move vertically from such an intersection.